# Reducing the precision of numbers - regex vim

Tags: regex, vim, decimal, precision

My regex is quite rusty. How could vim be used to change the precision of a decimal number.

For example:

Changing 30.2223221 8188.2121213212
to       30.22      8188.21

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's likely possible using vim internal search/replace, but I would use "perldo":

```
:perldo s/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.2f", $1/eg
```

Comment: I modified this regex to also work with negative numbers and e-notation: ([-]?\d+\.\d+(e[+-]\d)?)

Answer (score 18):

Using just VimL:

`:%s/\d\+\.\d\+/\=printf('%.2f',str2float(submatch(0)))/g`

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to truncate the last digit instead of rounding,

```
:%s/(\d+\.\d\d)\d+/\1/g
```

Comment: The above did not work for me, but adding a few slashes fixes it... :%s/\(\d\+\.\d\d\)\d\+/\1/g

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answers, using VimL, for negative numbers and exponential notation:

```
:%s/\c\v[-]=\d+\.\d+(e[+-]\d+)=/\=printf('%.2f',str2float(submatch(0)))/g
```